# Compile FFMPEG Using Eclipse Android

Tags: compiler-errors, android-ndk, ffmpeg

NDK experts , I need your help...

My goal is to easily compile [ffmpeg](http://www.ffmpeg.org/) library using android NDK and eclipse.

What I usally do when I want to develop using NDK , is right click on android project in eclipse ->Android Tools -> Add Native support. And Everything works and compiles.
Every time I want to build my project , I just hit "Build" button (with a hammer icon on it).

Now I just need to add all ffmpeg libraries and run a simple program like [this](http://dranger.com/ffmpeg/tutorial01.html).
I downloaded latest ffmpeg libraries from [official website](http://www.ffmpeg.org/download.html).I've extracted downloaded content into JNI library . And when I try to build , I get countless errors. Something like
 *"fatal error: libavutil/avconfig.h: No such file or directory"* ...

My Android.mk file looks like this :

```
LOCAL_PATH := $(call my-dir)

include $(CLEAR_VARS)
include $(call all-subdir-makefiles)

LOCAL_MODULE    := HELLONDK
LOCAL_SRC_FILES := hello-ndk.cpp

include $(BUILD_SHARED_LIBRARY)
```

**EDIT :**
I've been looking for a solution for a few days before posting this question.

Comment: go to github. search on 'android-ffmpeg'  and pick a popular project. Using the latest ffmpeg source not the way to go.

Comment: Did you do that ? Did you find project that compiles ? I didn't.

Comment: For example this one looks promising , but doesn't compile . https://github.com/appunite/AndroidFFmpeg

Comment: Maybe it's your build process?

Comment: i have used 'halfninja' and 'guardian'. both build fine on ubuntu

Comment: suggestion: take android out of the picture for a little while and get familiar with building ffmpeg for your platform...  https://trac.ffmpeg.org/wiki/UbuntuCompilationGuide

Comment: I guess you are right...There will no be a simple solution...

Answer (score 0):

http://sourceforge.net/projects/ffmpeg4android/

I believe this will greatly help; altho i'm unsure whether eclipse is up to this task...
It seems like this is intended only for building against the full source, but there seems to be an addon by some guy Sergei - http://sourceforge.net/p/ffmpeg4android/discussion/general/thread/43c119e6/?limit=25#c7d4

try seeing there.

Comment: Thanks. Doesn't compile. Did you try it ?

Comment: I know the guy maintaining it, so I know it compiles if you follow the instructions. However, I did not try it recently so something might have broken in the meantime...